# how can we flatten a list in rdd, I am stuck at below status with my trial

Tags: pyspark

Friends ..
I have an rdd that contains a row "[(1,0), (1,1), (1,0)]" 
Out of this, my aim is to get an rdd that has a  row [(1,0,1,0)]" 
I have tried below code to achieve this and stuck up at below status

```
mylist = [(1,0), (1,1), (1,0)]
myrdd = sc.parallelize(mylist)
result = myrdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
result.collect()
```

Output is: [(1, [0, 1, 0])]

but I want to see the output as [(1,0,1,0)] ..  please help ..

Comment: Can you explain why `[(1,0), (1,1), (1,0)]` becomes `[(1,0,1,0)]`? What is the transformation you're looking to do?

Also, your input is not really a row, it is a list of of 3 elements where each element is a Tuple of 2 integers?

Answer (score 0):

before collecting add the line:

```
result = result.map(lambda (k, l): tuple([k] + l))
```